# How to avoid Laravel Mix overriding app.css

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

The content of style.css gets overridden eahc time I run `npm run dev`
This is my webpack file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

 mix.styles(['resources/assets/style.css'], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Any way to append the css and not override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app` is the default name taken by the webpack

So either change 
 `.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css') ->  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/newfile.css')`

or

`mix.styles(['resources/assets/style.css'], 'public/css/app.css') -> mix.styles(['resources/assets/style.css'], 'public/css/styles.css')`

Edit: If you need everything in one file

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
mix.styles(['public/css/app.css', 'resources/assets/style.css'], 'public/css/app.css')
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change your webpack file.

In addition to importing `.sass` and `.scss` files, Sass can import plain old `.css` files. The only rule is that the import must not explicitly include the `.css` extension, because that’s used to indicate a plain CSS `@import`.

**Webpack**

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

**Sass** (`resources/assets/sass/app.scss`)

```
...

@import '../style.css';
```